# How do I implement a scheduled task without trigger event for a telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to create a bot to get rid of inactive users. The users information is logged into a database (MariaDB) upon joining the group. Every time they send a message, a timestamp (DATETIME) is updated in the database. The goal is to write a function which is able to recurrently remove people who have been inactive for a week or more.

I have written a function that would be able to do that (with the aid of some utility functions that I implemented to retrieve data from my DB):

```py
async def RemoveUsers(update: Update) -> None:
    = “TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,LAST_TIMESTAMP,NOW())>1”
    success, data = db.select(tablename, “*”, condition)

    if success and len(data):
        db.delete(tablename, condition)
        for (uid, _) in data:
            update.effective_chat.ban_member(uid, until_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=30))

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
remove_inactive = scheduler.add_job(RemoveUsers, “interval”, days = 1, args = (?, ))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler.start()

    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(API_KEY).build()

    # Other handlers here...

    application.run_polling(allowed_updates = Update.ALL_TYPES, drop_pending_updates = True)
```

But how am I supposed to pass the updates to the function? I don't want to set up a trigger event (like a command or new message or whatever). I would like this to run every day on its own. However, I cannot think of a way to do this. Is there a better way I could write this?

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**: I have thought about using `JobQueue` from the `python-telegram-bot` module. However, it still does not solve my problem, as the function itself would still need to an event to trigger it.

If it matters, I am using Python v3.9.5 and `python-telegram-bot` v20.6.

Comment: Have you thought about using cron?

Comment: @puf I did a little quick Google search and it seems that cron is used to recurrently run a file on a schedule(?). But what I really want to do is more within the script itself. I guess cron might be a bit of a brute-force solution in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `RemoveUsers` function is supposed to be called in regular intervals rather than when an update is received, there is no use of having an `Update` object as argument. What you really need in that function is the ID of the chat that you want to ban the users from. This can either be hard-coded or passed to RemoveUsers as argument.

Note that basically the same argument holds for PTBs `JobQueue` (which is basically a wrapper around APScheduler). See also [this wiki entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-am-i-getting-an-error-the-following-arguments-have-not-been-supplied). Moreover, note that you don't need an update from Telegram to schedule a job via the `JobQueue` - just run `application.job_queue.run_daily(…)` after defining the `application`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem :)